# PHP Imagick stroke appears over fill

Tags: php, imagemagick, imagick

Attempting to do a simple watermark consisting of white text with black outline on top of an image. Problem is that the stroke color is appearing over (or at least affecting) the fill color. What I mean by "affecting" is that, for example, when I try a red stroke color the fill color becomes a slightly lighter red (ie red + white) because I have a fill color of white.

**Image**

[image]

Code:

```
$watermark_text = new ImagickDraw();
$watermark_text->setFont($font);
$watermark_text->setFontSize(25);
$watermark_text->setFillColor('white');
$watermark_text->setStrokeColor('#000000');
$watermark_text->setStrokeWidth(3);
$watermark_text->setStrokeOpacity(0.4);
$watermark_text->setStrokeAntialias(false);
$watermark_text->setGravity(Imagick::GRAVITY_SOUTHEAST);
```

I specified .4 opacity to see/show that the fill and solid are actually there, just not fully in the way I expect.

I am expecting the fill color to be 100% white, any ideas why it's not please?

Thank you

---

Edit

I see what's happening. The stroke width is such that it overlaps the fill internally. Is there a way to ensure that the fill color appears on top of the stroke so that the white is 100% white?

Comment: Please show enough code to reproduce the problem - you don't show the canvas size, nor the code where you actually write the text...

Comment: @appl3s The code doesn't match the image you're showing, and isn't complete. Please can you improve your question?

Comment: thank you for the comments, I clearly did a poor job of showing the code, my mistake. @emcconville below correctly diagnoses and resolves the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like your point size is to small for stroke width of 3. The effects your experiencing can be demonstrated with the following example.

```php
foreach(range(1,5) as $strokeWidth) {
    // ... your example here ...
    $watermark_text->setStrokeWidth($strokeWidth);
    $watermark_text->annotation(0, 0, 'Font Width ' . $strokeWidth);
}
```

[image: stroke appears over fill]

The easiest solution would be to `clone` your `ImagickDraw`, and draw the same text twice. First being only the outline w/out fill, and the actual filled text over the top of the first. If your not working with vectors, you can also drop the opacity steps in favor of `rgba` color.

```php
// Create white text w/ common options
$font = 'Helvetica-Neue-Bold';
$watermark_text = new ImagickDraw();
$watermark_text->setFillColor('white');
$watermark_text->setFont($font);
$watermark_text->setFontSize(25);
$watermark_text->setStrokeAntialias(false);
$watermark_text->setStrokeColor('none');
$watermark_text->setStrokeWidth(0);
$watermark_text->setGravity(Imagick::GRAVITY_SOUTHEAST);
// Clone & set stroke attributes
$watermark_outline = clone $watermark_text;
$watermark_outline->setFillColor('none');
$watermark_outline->setStrokeColor('rgba(0,0,0, 0.4)');
$watermark_outline->setStrokeWidth(3);
// Set the text for both, and offset one to match stroke width
$watermark_outline->annotation(0, 0, 'Draw On Top');
$watermark_text->annotation(3, 0, 'Draw On Top');
// Draw stroke, then text
$image = new Imagick();
$image->setSize(200, 35);
$image->readImage('XC:LightGoldenrod');
$image->drawImage($watermark_outline);
$image->drawImage($watermark_text);
$image->writeImage('out.png');
```

[image: draw on top]

Comment: thanks very much @emcconville, this was the issue and your solution resolves it.